# Python: how to heatmappize values in [0, 1] range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, heatmap

I have a set of probabilities ranging from 0 to 1 and I would like to map them to heapmap-alike colors, e.g. to one of those:

[image]

then color will be used for *matplotlib* graphs.

How do I do it the most simple way in Python?

Comment: Question is unclear. Colormaps are always between 0 and 1 in matplotlib.

Comment: I need to transform float value between 0 and 1 to the actual color of the heatmap. How do I do it?

Comment: just multiply the value for 255

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the question really is how to obtain the rgb color corresponding to a value between 0 and 1 from  a predifined colormap in matplotlib, the answer would be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print plt.cm.jet(0.5)
```

which prints `(0.49019607843137247, 1.0, 0.47754585705249841, 1.0)`. This is the rgba tuple, so last entry is alpha (=transparency).

Comment: oh no, not jet :(

Comment: The question is very hard to interprete, but because the question shows a jet colormap it makes sense to provide the answer using it. This is of course applicable to [any other colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), like  `plt.cm.<name of cmap>`.

Comment: The answer is perfect, I just don't like jet :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (transform a number between 0 and 1 to an rgba value, according to some predefined colormap), I think that matplotlib.colors and matplotlib.cm can do what you need. Assuming you are using 'jet' colormap, as I think is the case given your pictures:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib import cm as cmx
jet = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=jet)
scalarMap.to_rgba(0)
# returns (0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0), i.e. blue
scalarMap.to_rgba(0.5)
# returns (0.49019607843137247, 1.0, 0.47754585705249841, 1.0) i.e. green
scalarMap.to_rgba(1)
# returns (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) i.e. red
```

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: That seems to be highly complicated for such an easy task. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42976032/4124317).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're definitely right, your question goes much more straight to the point!